# Alternative to Cache Insert fuction in Net framework

Tags: asp.net-core, frameworks

I am trying to set up this code https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/18/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/ (this code should be able to cyclically run some procedure on the same time - for example I need to update a database).
But I am currently using the ASP.NET Core 3.1 and there is no Insert function to the cache. I have managed other things around (for example other name of the delegate) but there is no chance with this issue.
Unfortunately I am still a begginer in C# so some things are still hard for me. I would appreciate any advice. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core supports several different caches. The simplest cache (In-memory cache) is based on the IMemoryCache. By using the cache's [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.set?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_CacheExtensions_Set__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_IMemoryCache_System_Object___0_Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_MemoryCacheEntryOptions_) method, you could create and add a new entry to the cache.

To use the Memory cache in asp.net core, you could refer the following steps:

First, register the MemoryCache in the ConfigureServices method of Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
    services.AddMvc();  
    services.AddMemoryCache();  
}
```

Then, refer the following code to use it:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;    
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;    
using System;    
    
namespace MemoryCacheApplication.Controllers    
{    
    public class HomeController : Controller    
    {    
        private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;    
    
        public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)    
        {    
            this.memoryCache = memoryCache;    
        }    
    }   
    public IActionResult Index()  
    {  
        DateTime currentTime;  
        bool isExist = memoryCache.TryGetValue("CacheTime", out currentTime);  
        if (!isExist)  
        {                 
            currentTime = DateTime.Now;                  
            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()  
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));  
  
            memoryCache.Set("CacheTime", currentTime, cacheEntryOptions);  
        }  
        return View(currentTime);  
    } 
}
```

More detail information, please check the [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Hello, I am working with your code but first thing I am trying to solve is that the cache which was set does not expire after those 30s (not even after 40 sec). Then I need to set up some PostEvictionDelegate which as I understand is called when the cache expires. By this delegate I would call the setup cache function again ... is it possible? Thank you again!

Comment: A while ago a have found that I need to use alo SetAbsoluteExpiration. Then it expires after the current number of seconds. Now I need to use somehow the delegate.